# How can one remove changesets from revision history of MQ repository?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, mercurial-queue, mercurial-extension

I have a Mercurial repository. It has a patch queue (which itself is a repository containing patches). Unfortunately I have performed too many unsightly commits to MQ (with `hg commit --mq` command).
If I run `hg history --mq` command, it will print tons of unnecessary changesets, say, A, B, B1, B2, B3, B4, C, D .
I just want to get rid of those B1, B2, B3 and B4, but I don't want to remove the latest C and D . Just those intermediate changesets.
How can I achieve the desired?

Comment: I am wondering why you would want to?  Once your patches are correct, wouldn't you `qfinish` them and commit them to the main repository?  No one will see the patch queue history except you.

Comment: You'd have to edit the history of the patch queue, using a patch queue for the patch queue...gets confusing.  `qimport` the history you don't want, and use `qdel` or `qfold` to remove or compress the history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there are no conflicts between the subsequent mq changesets, it's quite simple.

The mq way is to use `hg qdelete PATCH-ID` with the patches you want to see removed. It is mandatory that the patches are NOT applied.

Alternatively you can use the normal hg way to edit your mq repository:

- unapply all mq changesets: `hg qpop --all`
- Edit the .hg/patches/series file and remove the lines of the patches you want to see removed
- check that all remaining patches apply cleanly, best done one by one, thus do a `hg qpush` for each. Should there be any conflict fix it now.
- Commit the changes to the mq repository in .hg/patches

Should you require one of the intermediate patches, check for `hg qfold` and friends.

Comment: Look. This isn't what I really want. I'll try to explain it more clear.
See, I have a repository. `~/repo`. It has nothing inside.
In the `~/repo/.hg/patches` there is an MQ repository, which contains patches (say, `patch_sin`, `patch_cos`, `patch_log`, `patch_tan`).
If I run `hg history` inside `~/repo`, I will always get nothing, because nothing is done directly in the repository. But if I run `hg history` inside `~/repo/.hg/patches` **or** `hg history --mq` inside `~/repo`, I'll get the list of changesets to MQ repository, not the base repository.

Comment: For example, I work on those patches. Say, I was sitting and writing down the code to implement `cos()` function inside the `patch_cos` patch. And I did multiple commits. So if I watch history, I'll see something like:

Comment: changeset:   (N+2):blah-blah-hash-(N+1)  
user:        Isroel Barenboim <Isroel.Barenboim@shalom-tech-online.co.il>  
date:        Mon Jan 04 11:59:08 2016 +0300  
summary:     Final version

Comment: changeset:   (N+1):blah-blah-hash-N
user:        Isroel Barenboim <Isroel.Barenboim@shalom-tech-online.co.il>
date:        Mon Jan 04 11:53:08 2016 +0300
summary:     Attempt to debug the function N

. . .

changeset:   2:blah-blah-hash-2
user:        Isroel Barenboim <Isroel.Barenboim@shalom-tech-online.co.il>
date:        Sun Dec 13 11:53:08 2015 +0300
summary:     Attempt to debug the function 1

changeset:   1:blah-blah-hash
user:        Isroel Barenboim <Isroel.Barenboim@shalom-tech-online.co.il>
date:        Sat Dec 12 11:53:08 2015 +0300
summary:     Stub for cos() function added

Comment: I **do not** want to delete any of patches, such as `patch_cos` or `patch_tan`. What I want is to remove or somehow fold those ugly **revisions** of the patch queue from "Attempt to debug the function 1" to "Attempt to debug the function N".
Only "Stub for cos() function added" and "Final version" should remain.

Comment: @IsroelBarenboim, you should update your question with this expanded explanation.  It is hard to follow as comments.

Comment: Yes, please update your question accordingly. It becomes a different question with these clarifications.